# How to add a router config by env in Phoenix Framework

Tags: phoenix-framework, distillery

I'm developing a telegram bot for twitter, the source code is open sourced on github https://github.com/chenxsan/telegram-bot-for-twitter. But I want to protect the webhook by hiding it, so I'm reading the webhook from config:

```
scope "/api", TweetBotWeb do
    pipe_through :api
    post "/#{Application.get_env(:tweet_bot, :webhook)}", TwitterController, :index
  end
```

And in `prod.secret.exs`:

```
config :tweet_bot, webhook: "${WEBHOOK}"
```

But after built with https://github.com/bitwalker/distillery/, the release won't read `WEBHOOK` from env, so i just got 404 error.

Is it possible to do it in PhoenixFramework? If yes, how can I make it?

Comment: I'm not 100% famailiar with Distillery, but I think Gigalixir's documentation might point you in the right direction - http://gigalixir.readthedocs.io/en/latest/main.html#using-environment-variables-in-your-app. Basically, I believe there's a `REPLACE_OS_VARS=true` option?

Comment: @Mitkins yes, I already set it true.